# Jupyter reload custom.css?

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Jupyer 4.3.0. I find that when I update my `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`, the changes are not reflected in my notebook until I kill `jupyter-notebook` and start it again. This is annoying, so how can I make Jupyter Notebook recognize the custom.css file changes without completely restarting the notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Jupyter 5.0. 
Right now I've tried to edit `custom.css` and the changes are reflected immediately after reloading a page without restarting.

I'm not sure about 4.3 version, but I guess it should work the same way. What did the property you change?

Comment: In fact, this works. I just needed to reload the page. The problem was that I was expecting Jupyter to detect the CSS change and refresh the page automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `/custom/custom.css` stopped working for me when I generated a config file, but if anyone stumbles to this problem too, the solution is to uncomment the line `c.NotebookApp.extra_static_paths = []` in the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file and add `"./custom/"` - or whatever path you chose for your custom css - inside the brackets.

P.S.: OS is Linux Manjaro 5.12 and Jupyter Notebook version is 6.3.0.